# update not working correctly on button

Tags: c#

Good day, My code below is not working. What it was supposed to do is to update all record with `scee='WP'` to `'RTP'` when button is clicked. I'm really new to this. I'm sorry.

```
using (MySqlConnection resetcon1 = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    resetcon1.Open();
    string scee = "WP";

    MySqlCommand resetcom1 = 
        new MySqlCommand("UPDATE t_table SET scee=@scee WHERE scee ='RTP' ", resetcon1);

    resetcom1.Parameters.AddWithValue("scee", scee);
    resetcom1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    resetcon1.Close();
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: No need to add parameters. Your sql command should look more like this if I am understanding you right: UPDATE t_table SET scee='RTP' WHERE scee='WP'

Comment: I'll try it out sir!~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is here you will change scee to "WP" where scee is equal to "RTP".

```
 "UPDATE t_table SET scee=@scee WHERE scee ='RTP' "
```

If you want to do the opposite as mentioned in your question it should be:

```
 "UPDATE t_table SET scee='RTP' WHERE scee =@scee "
```

You might need to add '' like this too:

```
 "UPDATE t_table SET scee='RTP' WHERE scee ='@scee' "
```